# why do i see .gitignored files/folders present inside a git repo?

Tags: git, github

i am talking about http://www.github.com/cakephp/cakephp for example. In that repo, the [`.gitignore`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/.gitignore) file says the folder `/plugins` is ignored. However, the source ***does*** include the `/plugins` folder in the repo. How is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can explicitly `git add` files you ignore or ignore files you previously committed to the repo.  All the `.gitignore` does is prevent future `git status` and `git add` from including those files.

In your example it may be that there are a lot of randomly named build products in `/plugins` that are annoying and the author just wanted to quickly get them out of `git status`.  Or it may be common to clone the project and drop in your own local plugins.

Comment: regarding ignoring files i previously committed to the repo........... i just experimented a bit...  it doesn't stop git from tracking future changes of that file... if i have to stop git from tracking future changes of that file, then i have to `git rm --cached <filename>`... but then, the file gets removed from the repo itself... so i am still confused, how the gitignored files in the cakePHP repo are still existing in the repo and their changes are not being trakced by git?

Answer (score 1):

Adding .gitignore will exclude the files in /plugins when you are committing/pushing to the repo after you add the regex. It does not mean all the files would always be ignored.